# Tensorflow, equivalent of Theano's pydotprint?

Tags: tensorflow

In Theano, I can use pydotprint to generate a nice graph of my model.  Very useful for debugging, and for presenting too.  Is there an equivalent for TensorFlow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JHafdahl points out, [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) provides graph visualization for TensorFlow graphs, which includes support for summarizing complex nested subgraphs.

To visualize a graph, build a TensorFlow graph as normal, then add the following statements to your Python program:

```
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/path/to/logs", tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())
writer.flush()
```

Then, in a separate terminal, run TensorBoard to visualize your graph:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/logs --port 6006
```

Finally, connect to TensorBoard by opening `http://localhost:6006` in your web browser. Clicking on the "Graph" tab will show the visualization of your graph; see the [graph visualization tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/graph_viz/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html), which ships with Tensorflow. I use it to track the performance of my models and make sure they are converging.